# Safe use of high voltage in laboratory environment?

Tags: high-voltage, grounding, spark

I'm completing a project in the lab that requires a spark. As such I've acquired an ignition coil and can use the Lab's standard 12V DC power supply that connects to the 240V AC Mains to power the ignition coil. My issue is grounding the spark plug. I'm assuming that a spark plug doesn't offer much resistance (something about the voltage ionising the air and lowering resistance significantly?) and that even if it does the output voltage would be too much for the 12V supply to ground. What are my options?

EDIT (Details):

I don't have a schematic so I've drawn a small diagram showing my configuration:
[image: Simple Diagram of my Setup]

Comment: not sure about the spark plug outside of an engine, have you considered a simple tazer or similar for your application?

Comment: How do you plan on driving the coil's primary? Schematic, please...

Comment: @EMFields Done...Kinda

Answer (score 1):

If the 12 Volt power supply is through an isolation transformer then just ground the outside metal case of the spark plug to REAL GROUND. It would work fine. With me it worked. VTIngole

Comment: In my setup it is impractical to use the real ground, I operate from a multi storey building, is this really the only solution?

Comment: by REAL GROUND what I meant was a good earthing connecion..sorry for the misunderstanding.vtingole